# htaccess does not work rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been struggling with my `.htaccess` file for weeks now, I changed it many times but it just won't work.

I have this in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^/([^./]+)\.html$ category.php?id=$1 
RewriteRule ^/([^./]+)\.html$ tag.php?id=$1 
RewriteRule ^/([^./]+)\.html$ play.php?id=$1
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that mod_rewrite is turned on in Apache? Do you have access to httpd.conf? It would be better to do redirects there instead of with a .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your conditions are only being applied to the first rule. Each set of `RewriteCond`'s *only get applied to the immediately following `RewriteRule`*. So the conditions only get applied to `RewriteRule ^/([^./]+)\.html$ category.php?id=$1` and the last 2 rules have no conditions at all.
2. Your conditions is to rewrite something **that exists** to something else, which will cause a rewrite loop. You probably wanted:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   ```
3. Your 2nd and 3rd rules **will never be applied** because if someone requests `/some-page.html` the first rule's regex will match it and rewrite the URI to `/category.php?id=some-page`, then the next to rules will never match because the first rule already rewrote the URI to `category.php`.
4. Your regular expressions match a leading slash, URI's being applied in rewrite rules that are inside an htaccess file has the leading slash stripped out, so you want this instead:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^([^./]+)\.html$ category.php?id=$1
   ```

1, 2 and 4 is easy. 3, not so much. You're going to have to figure out a unique way to represent an html page as a category, tag, or play. You can't have all 3 look identical, there's no way to tell which one you want. Take:

```
/something.html
```

Is that supposed to be a category? A tag? or a Play? Who knows, your rewrite rules surely don't. But if you preface each with a keyword, then you can differentiate:

```
/category/something.html
/tag/something.html
/play/something.html
```

And your rules would look like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^category/([^./]+)\.html$ category.php?id=$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^tag/([^./]+)\.html$ tag.php?id=$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^play/([^./]+)\.html$ play.php?id=$1
```